# Unable to install Apache2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2.2

Trying to install apache2 on ubuntu 14.04, but gives following error

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Followed this http://askubuntu.com/questions/611354/error-installing-apache2 but no success

Comment: try downloading its source from here: http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi    and try to install again

Answer (score 4):

Looks like some packages are broken in your system, first fix them

```
dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-bin apache2
OR
sudo aptitude install apache2-bin apache2
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: SHOWS : -

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-bin : Depends: libapr1 (>= 1.5.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libaprutil1 (>= 1.5.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 but it is not installable or

               Depends: libaprutil1-ldap but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Can you try to remove unnecessary packages by executing `apt-get autoremove` and then try to install apache again. if this doesn't help try with aptitude.

Comment: Tried doing that but no help !

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get remove apache* && sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Answer (score 3):

Running this often solves issues with packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This may also help:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

See [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache/apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) Linode guide.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like some packages are either broken or downgraded packages are required:
for me i just purge the libaprutil1 package first then reinstall it using apache2.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

That;s it Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by following two steps..

```
   sudo echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list

   sudo apt-get update
```

Working now :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove Apache2 from your system

1. sudo apt-get purge apache2*

Remove folders and file of apache2

2. sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2

Reinstall Apache2

3. sudo apt-get install apache2

Answer (score 0):

add-apt-repository is not a package, so you just can't install it using sudo apt-get install add-apt-repository.

The package which contain add-apt-repository command is (and was all the time):

`software-properties-common`

not python-software-properties as you may think. You can check this using the following command:

`dpkg -S add-apt-repository`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some packages are either broken or downgraded packages are required: for me, I just purge the libaprutil1 package first and then reinstall it using apache2.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

```
sudo apt-get remove apache* && sudo apt-get install apache2
```

```
dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-bin apache2
OR
sudo aptitude install apache2-bin apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when trying to install Apache on a new system. I'd added the ondrej apache2 PPA, and changed the release name in the sources.list.d file to "lunar" from "jammy", and that was what caused the problem for me.

Here was the install error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 apache2-bin : Depends: libaprutil1-ldap but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libldap-2.5-0 (>= 2.5.4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I removed the ondrej apache2 PPA (had to change the release name back to "lunar" in the sources.list.d file first), did an apt update, then it all worked.